# I have got these error in my Manifest file. Any solution?

Tags: android-studio

> Error: tools:replace specified at line:8 for attribute
> android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified RestfulAPI.app
> main manifest (this file), line 7 Error
> Validation failed, exiting
>
> > RestfulAPI.app main manifest (this file)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.restfulapi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RestfulAPI"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
        <activity
            android:name=".DataViewActivity"
          />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your **application** tag.

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="@string/application _name"
```